# Write the registry value without redirect in Wow6432Node

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, registry, wow64

this code insert the registry value

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key;
            key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\MAIN\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION"); 
            key.SetValue("MyBrowser.exe", 8000);
            textBox1.Text = key.GetValue("MyBrowser.exe").ToString(); 
            key.Close();
```

in windows 32 bit work, but in 64 bit is inserted to wow6432node
how to disable the redirect?

Answer (score 8):

You need to open the key using [RegistryView.Registry64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryview.aspx). You specify this in the [OpenBaseKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openbasekey.aspx) method so you'll need to rejig your code a little.

Answer (score 5):

RegistryView is available only on .NET 4.  You might want to consider allowing your program to run as a 64-bit process so no redirection takes place.  VS2010 has new behavior, it forces apps to run in 32-bit mode on new projects.  Project + Properties, Build tab, change Platform target to AnyCPU.