# Adding key to registry goes into a different folder than specified

Tags: c#, registry, registrykey

I am trying to create a key in the uninstall entry in the registry in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` but when I run the code it instead creates it in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion`, I don't understand where it could be getting this path from.

Below is the code that I am using

```
private void addToRegistry(string installPath)
{
    using (RegistryKey parent = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall", true))
    {
        if (parent == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to open registry key. Installation cannot continue", "Registry Error", 
                MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
        try
        {
            RegistryKey key = null;
            string appParent = "Boardies Email Server";
            parent.CreateSubKey(appParent);
            key = parent.OpenSubKey(appParent);
            //key = parent.OpenSubKey(appParent, true) ??
            //    parent.CreateSubKey(appParent);
            if (key == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to add registry entry. Error: nInstallation Aborted", "Registry Error", 
                    MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                throw new Exception();
            }

            Assembly asm = GetType().Assembly;
            Version version = asm.GetName().Version;
            string exe = string.Format("{0}\\EmailServer.exe", installPath);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Failed to install, unable to insert into registry: {0}\n\nInstallation Aborted", ex.Message),
                "Registry Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Is this a 32 bits app or a 64 bits one?

Comment: possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311146/write-the-registry-value-without-redirect-in-wow6432node http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039186/c-sharp-reading-the-registry-and-wow6432node-key

Answer (score 1):

Probably, your application is 32 bits, in Windows x64 the Register is virtualized so 32 bits and 64 bits apps can coexist and use the same register keys; so your app sees that is writing in this path:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

But is really writing on this path:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
```

So in theory if you require such key from another 32 bits app, there should not be problems as it will also see this path as.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

Comment: Hmmm, this doesn't appear to be the case as I am trying to add the program into the Uninstall programs menu  doesn't show up in there when its in the Wow6432Node menu

Answer (score 0):

It is a [Registry Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa384232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Try using the [RegistryView Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryview.aspx) for [RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openbasekey.aspx), see the [RegistryView.Registry64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryview.aspx) enum member.

By the way, you can allow your program to run as a 64-bit process so there would be no redirection: Project => Properties => Build tab: change Platform target to *AnyCPU*.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have to change the value at the correct top level. You can identify the correct location with [autoruns.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902). It will point you to the right location!

(see example below in which I disabled a file system check when Windows boots up)

[image]

This tool not only locates all startup registry keys, but all other services as well, including 3rd party installs!